# Refactor jQuery $(this) into Vanila Js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I refactoring jQuery to Vanila JS, but i can't figure out how.

Let say i have the following jQuery code

```
 $('#simple').find('.single').each(function(){
    // I want to refactor $(this) into Vanilla JS
    var txt = $(this).find('.text').text();
  })
```

Let say i refactoring jQuery code into Vanilla Js but it does not work.

```
 document.getElementById('simple').queryAll('.single').forEach(function(){
   // It does not work this line
   var txt = document.getElementById(this).find('.text').text();  
  })
```

What is the real syntax? what is the equivalent of $(this) in Vanilla Js?

Comment: `queryAll`  invalid syntax

Comment: The error message plainly tells you that `queryAll` isn't a function; it's `querySelectorAll`. There's also `find()` or `text()` in Vanilla JS.

Comment: Both `queryAll` or `querySelectorAll` work for me. How to refactor $(this) to Vanilla Js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert this Jquery code

```
$('#simple').find('.single').each(function(){
    // I want to refactor $(this) into Vanilla JS
    var txt = $(this).find('.text').text();
  })
```

In vanilla js as follow

```
document.querySelectorAll('#simple .single').forEach(function(elm){
  var textElm = elm.querySelector('.text');
  var txt = textElm && textElm.innerText;
})
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: That is exactly what i want. Thanks.